# How are bpy.data.node_groups linked to the node_tree?

Tags: python

### NodeGroups

How are `bpy.data.node_groups` linked to `bpy.data.materials.node_tree` and what are the NodeGroups used for when the inputs there are also available `bpy.data.materials.node_tree` as there will be a "Node Group" node of type `GROUP`.